# Pytorch-Lightning Misconfiguration Exception; The closure hasn't been executed

Tags: python, transformer-model, pytorch-lightning

I have been trying to train a `torch.nn.TransformerEncoderLayer` using the standard Pytorch-Lightning `Trainer` class. Before the first epoch even starts, I face the following error:

**MisconfigurationException**: The closure hasn't been executed. HINT: did you call `optimizer_closure()` in your `optimizer_step` hook? It could also happen because the `optimizer.step(optimizer_closure)` call did not execute it internally.

I have very properly defined the `configure_optimizers()` method in the trainer and it works for every other model (say, LSTM, GRU, MultiHeadAttention). If I replace them with the TransformerEncoder, the aforementioned error pops up.

---

Here is the model code I am using:

```
class PositionalEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model=512, max_seq_len=512):
        super().__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        pe = torch.zeros(max_seq_len, 
                         d_model)
        
        for pos in range(max_seq_len):
            for i in range(0, d_model, 2):
                pe[pos, i] = sin(pos / (10000 ** ((2 * i)/d_model)))
                pe[pos, i+1] = cos(pos / (10000 ** ((2 * (i + 1))/d_model)))
                
        pe = pe.unsqueeze(0)
        self.register_buffer('pe', pe)
 
    def forward(self, x):
        x *= sqrt(self.d_model)
        x += self.pe[:,:x.size(1)]
        return x
```

```
class TRANSFORMER(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, 
                 input_dim,
                 d_model=512,
                 nhead=8,
                 num_layers=6,
                 dropout=0.5,
                 use_scheduler=True,
                 num_tags=len(TAG2IDX),
                 total_steps=1024,
                 train_dataset=None,
                 val_dataset=None,
                 test_dataset=None):
        
        super().__init__()
        self.crf = CRF(num_tags=num_tags, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(d_model, num_tags)
        self.use_scheduler = use_scheduler
        
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=input_dim, 
                                      embedding_dim=d_model, 
                                      padding_idx=0)
        
        self.pos_encoder = PositionalEncoder(d_model=d_model)
        
        self.encoder_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=d_model,
                                                        nhead=nhead,
                                                        dropout=dropout,
                                                        activation="gelu",
                                                        batch_first=True)
        
        self.encoder = nn.TransformerEncoder(encoder_layer=self.encoder_layer,
                                             num_layers=num_layers)
        ## Hyperparameters ##
        self.learning_rate = LEARNING_RATE
        self.weight_decay = WEIGHT_DECAY
        self.total_steps = total_steps
        self.batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
        ## Datasets ##
        self.train_dataset = train_dataset
        self.val_dataset = val_dataset
        self.test_dataset = test_dataset
        ## steps ##
        if self.use_scheduler: 
            self.total_steps = len(train_dataset) // self.batch_size


    # create the dataloaders
    # add shuffle only for train_dataloader
    # make sure num_workers is set appropriately and drop_last is set to False
    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.train_dataset, 
                          batch_size=self.batch_size,
                          num_workers=N_JOBS,
                          shuffle=True,
                          drop_last=False)


    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.val_dataset, 
                          batch_size=self.batch_size,
                          num_workers=N_JOBS,
                          shuffle=False,
                          drop_last=False)


    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.test_dataset, 
                          batch_size=self.batch_size,
                          num_workers=N_JOBS,
                          shuffle=False,
                          drop_last=False)
    

    def forward(self, input_ids, masks):
        out = self.embedding(input_ids)
        out = self.pos_encoder(out)
        out = self.encoder(out, src_key_padding_mask=~masks)
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out

    
    def _shared_evaluation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        ids, masks, lbls = batch
        emissions = self(ids, masks)
        loss = -self.crf(emissions, lbls, mask=masks)
        pred = self.crf.decode(emissions, mask=masks)
        r, p, f1 = f1score(lbls, pred)
        return loss, r, p, f1


    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss, r, p, f1 = self._shared_evaluation_step(batch, batch_idx)
        self.log("train_loss", loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("train_recall", r, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("train_precision", p, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("train_f1score", f1, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss


    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss, r, p, f1 = self._shared_evaluation_step(batch, batch_idx)
        self.log("val_loss", loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("val_recall", r, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("val_precision", p, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("val_f1score", f1, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)

    
    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss, r, p, f1 = self._shared_evaluation_step(batch, batch_idx)
        self.log("test_loss", loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("test_recall", r, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("test_precision", p, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("test_f1score", f1, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)


    def predict_step(self, batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx=0):
        ids, masks, _ = batch 
        return self.crf.decode(self(ids, masks), mask=masks)
    
    
    def configure_optimizers(self):           
        optimizer = Ranger(self.parameters(), 
                           lr=self.learning_rate,
                           weight_decay=self.weight_decay)

        if self.use_scheduler:
            scheduler = get_cosine_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer=optimizer,
                                                        num_warmup_steps=1,
                                                        num_training_steps=self.total_steps)
            lr_scheduler = {
                'scheduler': scheduler, 
                'interval': 'epoch', 
                'frequency': 1
            }
            return [optimizer], [lr_scheduler]
        else:
            return [optimizer]
```

---

and here is how I am using the trainer class:

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(accelerator="gpu",
                     max_epochs=EPOCHS,
                     precision=32,
                     log_every_n_steps=1,
                     callbacks=[earlystopping_callback, 
                                checkpoint_callback])
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right. This happens because the special optimizer you have does not call the closure when passing it to the `.step()` method. But Lightning relies on this because it calls the step method like this:

```
optimizer.step(training_step_closure)
```

where `training_step_closure` consists of essentially [executing the `LightningModule.training_step`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/optimization.html#automatic-optimization).

It looks like Ranger does not follow the standard contract of calling the closure inside of itself.

To overcome this issue, I recommend switching to [manual optimization](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/optimization.html#manual-optimization):

1. Set `self.automatic_optimization = False` in your LightningModule.
2. Modify your training step by inserting manual backward, optimizer step and optionally the lr scheduler call:

Like so:

```
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    loss, r, p, f1 = self._shared_evaluation_step(batch, batch_idx)

    # Insert these lines:
    self.manual_backward(loss)
    
    optimizer = self.optimizers()
    scheduler = self.lr_schedulers()

    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    scheduler.step()

    ...
    return loss
```

No other changes should be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In that case, switching to a standard optimizer like Adam should also solve the issue, right?

Comment: Yes, definitely. All the standard optimizers follow this contract.